# How to perform a dynamic select query for multiple tables in oracle? using table name and column names as values from other table?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

i have a table having columns such schema name,table name,column name.

| schema name | table name | column name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dbo | product | colour |
| dbo | sales | quantity |
| dbo | customer | order |

i want to perform an action such that to get a count of records based on column as column name and table as table name

```
select count(colour) as count from dbo.product
select count(quantity) as count from dbo.sales
select count(order) as count from dbo.customer
```

can u suggest me correct steps to achieve this using Oracle database. thanks in advance

expected output

| count |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 50 |
| 150 |

Comment: How do you want to consume this data? I mean what should be the output since there can be a lot of tables and columns, but result should compose them in some way (you cannot have multiple result sets in Oracle, only via parameters of procedure).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get count per column per table, you can do this with plain SQL using [`DBMS_XMLGEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS374) package, which essentially executes new cursors dynamically.
I think you can adapt the example query below to suit your needs (aggregate counts or convert them to another format).

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     'all_tables' as table_name, 'table_name' as column_name
>   from dual
>   union all
>   select 'all_tables', 'tablespace_name' from dual union all
>   select 'all_tab_cols', 'column_name' from dual union all
>   select 'all_indexes', 'index_name' from dual union all
>   select 'all_indexes', 'tablespace_name' from dual
> )
> select
>   table_name,
>   column_name,
>   cast(extractvalue(
>     dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
>       'select count(' || column_name || ') as cnt' || chr(10) ||
>       'from ' || table_name
>     ),
>     '/ROWSET/ROW/CNT'
>   ) as int) as cnt
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> TABLE_NAME   | COLUMN_NAME     |   CNT
> :----------- | :-------------- | ----:
> all_tables   | table_name      |    71
> all_tables   | tablespace_name |    43
> all_tab_cols | column_name     | 20983
> all_indexes  | index_name      |    81
> all_indexes  | tablespace_name |    73
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aef9edb45f57ab46cae00fe588c289bb)*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in pure sql, but you can pretty easily do this in pl/sql. In the code below I'm storing the results in a table called `rowcounts` and it assumes your table with tables and column names is called

```
CREATE table mytables (schema_name VARCHAR2(100), table_name, VARCHAR2(100), column_name VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO mytables (schema_name, table_name, column_name) VALUES ('dbo','product','colour');
INSERT INTO mytables (schema_name, table_name, column_name) VALUES ('dbo','sales','quantity');
INSERT INTO mytables (schema_name, table_name, column_name) VALUES ('dbo','customer','order');

CREATE TABLE rowcounts (table_name VARCHAR2(500), rowcount NUMBER);

DECLARE 
  l_rowcount INT;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM mytables) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT('||r.column_name||') FROM '||r.table_name INTO l_rowcount;
    --dbms_output.put_line('SELECT COUNT('||r.column_name||') FROM '||r.table_name);
    INSERT INTO rowcounts(table_name, rowcount) VALUES (r.table_name, l_rowcount);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/

--DROP TABLE rowcounts;
```